# Move an inactive quote to checkout

Tags: magento2, checkout, cart, quote

How to move an inactive quote to a checkout page.

At some point i change the active quote to an inactive quote. But after some times the customer will use this inactive quote and proceed to checkout.

Is there a way to make an inactive quote to an active

Answer (score 0):

Yes, we can activate the quote if you know the quote_id.

You can use the query to active the inactive quotes

> update quote set is_active=1 where entity_id = 'YOUR QUOTE ID GOES HERE'